# Deploying Workplace Add Ons (Google Apps Script) programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Gmail Add On built in Apps Script that I’m currently developing. It is unpublished.

To test my changes, I am:

1. Opening the project on script.google.com
2. *Manually copying and pasting changes into each file.*
3. Manually saving.
4. Clicking **Deploy > Test deployments > Uninstall > Install**.

This process is highly error prone and seems wrong. Is there some way to create a script like `deploy_add_on.sh`.

Same question for when the add-on is actually "published".

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons